# Building postgres from source and package as debian package

Tags: postgresql, debian, package, postgresql-9.6

Incase I prefer to build the postgresql from source let us say 9.6 and would prefer to package the same as debian on my own, is there any documentation that I can refer to figure out how postgres should be packaged after the build. Any scripts that I can refer in this regard?